# Непонятная проблема с telegram-ботом сделанным c помощью aiogram

Tags: telegram, aiogram

У меня возникла следующая проблема. Когда бот работает сам по себе, без добавления в чат, то все хорошо. Но будучи добавленным в чат он не обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку "сброс". Чем это может быть вызвано? При нажатии на кнопку сброс появляется сообщение "Введите название города" как и должно быть, но при попытке ввести его появляется сообщение типа - 2023-11-06 16:17:31,853 - [INFO] - aiogram.event - (dispatcher.py).feed_update(171) - Update id=838897882 is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=6559079465
Повторюсь - вне чата бот отрабатывает абсолютно корректно, я совершаю абсолютно те же действия в той же последовательности.  Где может быть проблема?

Вот мои хэндлеры.

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from core.utils.states import WeatherStates
from core.keyboards.inline import keyboard
from core.api_requests.request import get_weather
from core.utils.dbconnect import dbsave, dbselect
from core.settings import settings

bot = Bot(token=settings.bots.bot_token)
city = ''


async def get_start(message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Введите свой город:')
    await state.set_state(WeatherStates.waiting_for_city)
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    print(current_state)
    

async def help(message):
    await message.answer('Этот бот предоставляет информацию о погоде '
                         'в различных населенных пунктах. После ввода вашего '
                         'населенного пункта бот запомнит его и вам не придется '
                         'вводить его название повторно. Если же вы захотите изменить '
                         'его то нажмите кнопку "сброс" и введите новое название.')


async def get_city(message, state: FSMContext):
    global city
    city = message.text
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    city, temp_celsius, wind_speed, desc = await get_weather(city)
    await dbsave(user_id, city, temp_celsius, desc, wind_speed)
    # Запрос к API и вывод данных о погоде в сообщении
    await message.answer(f"Погода в {city}: {temp_celsius} градусов, {desc},\
 ветер {wind_speed} м/с")
    # Отправка инлайн клавиатуры с двумя кнопками "сброс" 
    # и "запросить погоду в {city}"
    await message.answer(text='Выберите действие', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await state.set_state(WeatherStates.waiting_for_choice)


async def request_weather(callback_query):
    global city
    message = callback_query.message
    user_id = message.from_user.id 
    city, temp_celsius, wind_speed, desc = await get_weather(city)
    await dbsave(user_id, city, temp_celsius, desc, wind_speed)
    city, temperature, describe, wind = await dbselect(user_id)
    await message.answer(f"Погода в {city}: {temp_celsius} градусов, {desc},\
 ветер {wind_speed} м/с")
    await message.answer(text='Выберите действие', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)


async def reset(callback_query, state: FSMContext):
    await state.clear()
    await get_start(callback_query.message, state)
```

Comment: Забыл написать, использую aiogram 3.0.0